Parity of a function
I am given the following definition:
If I have an operator $M_1$ such that $M_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and similarly for $M_2$ and $M_3$. If for a function $f(\vec x)$ we have $f(M_\alpha\vec x)=\pm f(\vec x)$, then $f(x)$ has positive parity $(f(M_\alpha\vec x)=f(\vec x))$ or negative parity  $(f(M_\alpha\vec x)=-f(\vec x))$.
So what is parity in this context? Wouldn't it be the same as saying the function is either even or odd?

Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/785353/2451

Parity in this context is a symmetry property of a function under specific transformation. Here it generalizes the idea of evenness or oddness to more complex transformations and dimensions.
